# How to reboot the nvidia graphics without having to reboot system?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, pop-os, proprietary-drivers

I have an issue which I believe to be my graphics driver crashing. Mostly this happens when I try to run a game or steam.

When I try to open steam and click on the icon it just won't open. Also when I try to play a game outside of steam I get a message along the lines of `No compatible graphics hardware was found`. Also when I use my system monitor I get a message that says `System Monitor has fallen back to software rendering because hardware acceleration is not available, and visual glitches may appear. Please check your graphics drivers.`

So this leads me to believe that the graphics driver crashed or something like that (I am still a bit of a newbie to Linux so I am not sure). I can reboot the whole system and this issue is resolved but it is very inconvenient specially when I am doing work or working on a project. Is there a way to run a command on the terminal or do something similar to just restart the driver?

Here is some information about my system:

- Intel 8 Core i7-7700K CPU @ 4.20GHz
- Nvidia GeForce GTX 1060 6GB
- 16 GB RAM
- Pop OS 22.04
- KDE Plasma Version 5.24.7
- Kernel Version 6.0.12-76060006-generic (64-bit)

Here is the output to `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` :

`01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB] (rev a1) Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. DUAL-GTX1060-O6G [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB Dual] Kernel driver in use: nvidia Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia`

Comment: Can you please [Edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/734598/edit) your question and post the output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`?

Comment: Thank you for that. I have included the output to the command you mentioned. Let me know if anything else is needed to get a better picture.